# how to replace deprecated "java.security.acl.Group" in java 14

Tags: java

hi i'm trying to create an authorization server with keycloack and spring boot , but i'm facing this issue "java.security.acl.Group" is deprecated in java 14 .
SO how can i replace this deprecated class ?
thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: Generally when classes get deprecated there is a recommended path for what to replace that class with.  You can got to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/acl/Group.html to read up and follow Oracle's recommendation for what to replace it with (java.security.Policy and related classes)